# What is a "Norman genitive"?

Tags: terminology, possessives

I have encountered such a term, and I have no idea what it is. Could it be 'of'?

Comment: -1 for absolutely no research effort.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Norman genitive*, or *French genitive*, is another term for *analytic genitive*. The following phrases use the *Norman genitive*.

- the future of mankind
- the roof of your house
- the leaves of those trees

The following phrases use the *Saxon genitive*, or *synthetic genitive*.

- Michael's sister
- Joanna's boyfriend
- the cat's leg

Comment: Lovely!  There's a Saxon and a Norman genitive -- terms unknown to me before now!  I wonder if there's a Celtic genitive?

Answer (score 4):

The analytic genitive, also known as the French or Norman genitive, is the genitive in "of" form, like "The question of Lukas", "The answer of Phoenix", "The house of John", "the doors of the car".  The other form is the synthetic genitive, also known as the Saxon genitive, which is the possessive with the apostrophe, like "Lukas' question", "Phoenix's answer", "John's house", "The car's doors"

Answer (score 3):

A *Norman genitive* is simply placing "of" between two nouns to indicate possession:

- The voice *of* the people.
- The leaves *of* the tree.
- The violins *of* the concert band.

The owning noun (also known as the *noun in genitive*) is an attribute of the owned noun.

Answer (score 3):

In Modern English, both constructions are frequently encountered, as pointed out in the other answers. 
There is, however, a decided preference for use of the Saxon genitive with human or animate possessors,

- **the house of Bill ~ Bill's house*
- **the leg of Fido ~ Fido's leg*

but the Norman genitive with inanimate possessors:

- **the table's foot ~ the foot of the table*
- **the day's middle ~ the middle of the day*

As usual, Language makes opportunistic use of an accidental form distinction to mark a functional distinction.

Comment: There is also _week's schedule_. I don't think there is a preference for _the schedule of the week_, instead of _week's schedule_.

Comment: There are a lot of fixed phrases with common nouns like _day, week,_ etc. This being December, we're seeing a lot of lists now headed *The Year's Best X,* or even *2011's Best X.* This is a tendency, not a fixed rule.

Comment: I knew a person, native speaker of American English, who uses the Saxon genitive also with inanimate objects. As she was born in 1952, I am not sure that is a tendency.