# When do we use "of" rather than " 's" to show possession?

Tags: possessives, possessive-s-vs-of, saxon-genitive

It is a very simple word but I am quite confused when I write formal documents.
I do not know exactly when to use the **of** rather than **'s**. For example:

> The value of the mean or The mean's value.
>
> The domains of statistics or The statistics' domains.
>
> The example of data or data's example.

I have searched on Google. Both cases seem widely used on many websites, so I do not know which one is well received by native speakers. Are there guidelines for choosing one over the other?

Comment: The general pattern is to use the suffix _-'s_ for possessors that animate, including humans, and to use a prepositional phrase with _of_ for inanimate possessors. Thus, _the leg of the table_ but _the horse's leg_. There are many exceptions and idioms, however.

Comment: See for instance the excellent answers on this closed question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52104/what-is-a-norman-genitive

Comment: @JohnLawler So, the data's example is the false sentence. Right?

Comment: Right. None of the abstract terms you used should have the suffix; this is especially true for metaphors, like _head/foot/leg of the table_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My English professor told me that we use ***of*** when we are talking about something that is part of or related to another thing. For example, *ceiling of my room* or *subject of the lecture.* But ***'s*** is used when we are speaking about the ownership relationships and usually related to a person. For example *Ali's car* or *students' room*.

But according to my researches, we use ***of*** to indicate that one thing is either related to or about something else.  On the other hand we use ***'s*** to show that two or more things are part of or under the ownership of each other in some ways.

Comment: There are exceptions, though: one might easily say "That car's headlamp is broken."