# University's possession or possession of the university

Tags: grammaticality

When we state that something belongs to a university, for instance requirements, we should use university's requirements or requirements of the university?

I remember learning like a thing that belongs to a non-living thing should be written as something of something instead of something's something. However, I see usage of university's something all over the place.

Pardon for the number of "something" in my questions.

Comment: I have never heard of any rule which prohibits the use of the possessive case with inanimate or abstract nouns. *My car's windscreen wipers got a lot of use today, and my computer's keyboard is starting to give trouble.* I see nothing whatever wrong with saying "The University's entrance requirements have been relaxed".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saxon genitive usage question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15679/saxon-genitive-usage-question). There is additional comment at [What is a Norman genitive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52104/what-is-a-norman-genitive/52109#52109).

Comment: And perhaps the fullest discussion at [Apostrophe-s vs of](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/apostrophe-s-vs-of/30397#30397).